# Running Python Interactively in Python

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to use subprocess to run python interactively within python. When I run the following script, it hangs on my read from stderr.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('python', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)

text = p.stderr.read(256)
p.stdin.write('exit()\n')
p.close()
```

If however I make a tiny change to remove `stdin=subproces.PIPE` from the constructor, it works successfully and `text` gets assigned the output from `p.stderr` and then fails on p.stdin.write(..) with `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'`

Why does this hang? I'm trying to keep a a subprocess open to read from it and write to it at will.

I'd like to do this single threaded. The my 'main' script opens python then a loop runs which gets input from a user. If the user inputs 'r' it reads from the process, if they enter 'w' it writes to the process.

The more I search and the more I test out different solutions, it seems as though it's just not possible to pipe both an input & an output stream with python subprocess. I can run the program fine and read stderr if i'm not passing in stdin=PIPE. I've also tried using a different named file for each file pointer but no success.

Still fighting this battle. Just as a note, if anyone else is familiar with the ruby world, what I want to do is possible with the "[ChildProcess](https://github.com/enkessler/childprocess)" gem. There's gotta be a way with python

Comment: I'd suggest to use `p.communicate()` instead of directly writing to stdin, which is alway prone to deadlocks.  However, I can't see how this is going to be useful.

Comment: p.communicate() blocks. I don't make it to the stdin call as it blocks on the call to stderr.read although output is available.

Comment: There are a lot of differences in how this works between python versions.. or at least there used to be.  What version of python are you running and what process are you running?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: python 2.7.11 via anaconda 4.0.0 (32-bit). Trying to run python itself

Comment: You should remove the call to stderr.read().  And I don't think output is available.  Python doesn't print the copyright notice if its stdin is connected to a pipe.

Comment: You should also remove `shell=True`, and there is no `close()` method for `subprocess.Popen` objects.  Anyway, the whole thing seems utterly useless.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to launch processes from within the behave framework for testing. I've wrote this simple script to test and confirm its not working as expected

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to launch a Python from inside another Python?  Normally you'd just `import` something and run a function.

Comment: I think this may be what @SvenMarnach mentioned in that there is no banner being printed to stderr when stdin is piped. I'm not sure how to prove this yet but will have to dig into the python src at some point

Comment: You don't need to dig into the source.  Simply reading Python's man page should be enough.  You can also run `python <<< ""` from a bash shell and verify that it doesn't print anything.  In non-interactive mode, Python will read the whole input before compiling it, so it just won't do what you intend.  If you want to execute Python code, the current interpreter will do that just fine.  There is no need for a second one in the child process.  You might want to use the `exec` statement and pass in a separate global namespace, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "Sven Marnach" said,

> Python doesn't print the copyright notice if its stdin is connected
>   to a pipe

The subprocess that was launched blocked as there was no out available to read. Solved this by polling for output.